# Maven's Lifecycle in Dockerfile

Tags: maven, docker, dockerfile

First of all thanks for your time. Im trying to run maven commands inside dockerfile:

```
# Base container contains maven, jdk on ubuntu
FROM maven:3-jdk-8
# copy my build config pom file to container
ADD pom.xml /app/
# copy the source file directory to the container
ADD src/ /app/src/
# move the app directory inside container to perform mvn buill
WORKDIR /app/
RUN ["mvn", "dependency:resolve"]  
RUN ["mvn", "verify"]
# resolve dependency offline as suggested by Nicolas
#RUN mvn dependency:go-offline
# build by using maven
RUN mvn package
```

But Im having problems with the proxy:

```
$ docker build -t mavenimagen .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 124.9 kB
Step 1 : FROM maven:3-jdk-8
 ---> b2ef69e414f5
Step 2 : ADD pom.xml /app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 57e5b52fe34b
Step 3 : ADD src/ /app/src/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ace1a117cb4f
Step 4 : WORKDIR /app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> da544b2298a1
Step 5 : RUN mvn dependency:resolve
 ---> Running in 26258aec0093
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.4/maven-jar-plugin-2.4.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.4
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/2.1/maven-shade-plugin-2.1.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:jar:2.1
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom
```

I suppose that i must to add settings.xml but I don't know if i have to add in the root of my project or another directory.

Greettings !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted the exact proxy issue you have, but whatever it is, you probably have to put your custom `settings.xml` file (`ADD settings.xml /app/`) and then use it with Maven (`RUN mvn -s settings.xml package`).

If it will be more than one invocation, I recommend to put `settings.xml` to `~/.m2/` so it will be used by default on every Maven call.

Comment: I tried your recommendation  but i didn't see results. By the way I modified my question, I added my problem with the proxy. Thanks for your answer and your time :)

Comment: No I see which Maven call causes the issue. It's `RUN mvn dependency:resolve`. If you change it to `RUN mvn -s settings.xml dependency:resolve` it will be OK. Or, if it now more than one, just put `settings.xml` file to your `~/.m2/`, as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, the problem was the proxy.

I had to add this line in the dockerfile

```
ADD settings.xml /root/.m2/settings.xml
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Is this is the only application you are trying to build? If not I would recommend building two images as below:

- Maven build image: Contains java and maven with your settings xml in ~/.m2. This image has a volume mount for the sources code so it can be used multiple times e.g. within your CI/CD pipeline.
- App image: This image has only java to run the application and can be used to run the containers even in production.

HTH!!!